# Print decimal numbers in php

Tags: php

How can I print decimal numbers like

0.05

0.10

0.15

0.20

0.25

0.30

0.35

0.40

0.50

.

.

.

1.25

Tried with below code but it does not work

```
     <?php
      $start = 1;
      $end = 3;
      $place = 0.5;

      $step = 0.05 / pow(10, $place);

      for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i = round($i + $step, $place))
      {
          echo $i . "\n";
      }

      ?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to output 0.5 before 0.10? And between 0.40 and 0.50 (the second time) you have 0.10 step all other exept the first is 0.05

Comment: @Andreas I need to add 0.05 to every number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a range of the values needed.
Here I create from 0 -> 5 with 0.05 increment.

```
$range = range(0, 5, 0.05);

foreach($range as $val){
    echo number_format($val, 2) . "\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/lFV2f

If the decimals are not important a simpler way to output would be with implode.

```
echo implode("\n", $range);
```

Comment: the result is not so
0.40
0.50

Comment: @Sakezzz OP has not responded yet to that in my comment. But most likely that too is a typo. Edit I see that he did answer it. *I need to add 0.05 to every number*

Answer (score 0):

Taking the problem literally, here is a way to solve it.

```
$start = 0.05;
$increment = 0.05;
for ($i=0; $i < 25; $i++) { 
    echo number_format($start, 2, '.', '').'<br>';
    $start += $increment;
}
```